# Connecting to MySQL data from Tableau - datetime error

Tags: mysql, ssl, odbc, tableau-api

I am having problems with MySQL ODBC driver when trying to connect to my MySQL database from Tableau. It sets up just fine, but these limitations

```
Tableau identified the following warnings for the ODBC data source named 'hits':
This aggregation is unsupported: Attribute
This function is unsupported: DATETIME with parameter types 'integer'
This is unsupported: SELECT ... INTO
This is unsupported: Temporary tables
```

cause that the most important data (datetime attributes) are inaccessible. Could there be some kind of workaround?

EDIT 11/03/2015:

It is also possible to create a TDC file that enables using SSL + native Tableau connector, as specified here http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/preparing-mysql-connection-using-ssl
Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use the native MySQL connection](http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/current/pro/online/en-us/help.htm#examples_mysql.html) when connecting to your data source and these limitations will no longer appear.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to use SSL connection with the native MySQL? I am not able to find any detailed configuration there ...

Comment: It's not possible to use SSL with the native MySQL connection. However there is a KB describing how to connect. Note that the KB does recommend extracting your data to remove any limitations imposed by the ODBC connection: http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/preparing-mysql-connection-using-ssl